# Why does the file window say "Custom Files"?

Tags: forms

I created an HTML form to upload a file, and set the file types so that the user knows what files it expects.

```
<form id="uploadListForm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploadList">
    <input id="uploadListButton" type="file" accept=".csv,.txt" name="file" >
    <input id="submitList" type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

The problem is that instead of the Windows Explorer window showing ".csv,.txt" as possible files, it shows "Custom Files", with "All Files" being the only other option. How can I get it to actually state the file extensions?

Answer (score 0):

the **accept** parament expects mime types
Example: image/*

Comment: I changed it to `text/plain` and it still says the same thing.

Comment: yes! it didnt work :( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-accept I tired on my computer and it either accepts .csv or .txt but adding both sets it to custom :(